# What is the latest version of nServiceBus that runs on .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I know the latest version requires 4.5

I've tried downloading and running 3.3.7, but I get the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NServiceBus.Core' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

How far back to I need to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to go back to [2.6](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/2.6.0.1504/src)...